# Regular expressions to find class declarations in C++ code

Tags: c++, regex

I need a regular expression for finding class declarations so I can add a #define before the "class" keyword.  The regular expression doesn't have to be perfect, just good enough that it catches most of the cases.

Comment: Should the regex match the entire (probably multi-line) declaration, or just the class keyword?  The latter is easy to get mostly right; for the former, a regex is probably the wrong tool.

Answer (score 3):

```
/.*class\s+([^{]+)\s*[:]?([^{]+){/
```

This should work for most class definitions, including template classes. The class name is captured in $1 and if it is a derived class, the base will be in $2.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
/^\s*class\s/
```

That should work reasonably well. I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 2):

```
/class\s+([^\s]+)/
```

This will capture the class name as $1 (or the equivalent in whatever regex framework you're using). This will *not* work for template classes that may have spaces inside the <> that follows the class name. Parsing that is something not doable with a regular expression, since it requires matching balanced pairs of angle brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Yannick's answer mostly covers it but it unfortunately also matches forward declarations (and subsequent text below them) and strict enums i.e. `enum class myStrictEnum { // stuff };`

This works well and is strict enough, but is arguably more verbose than it need be.

```
^(?!enum).*class\b\s\b[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*\b\s*($)?(|:\s*($)?(public|private|protected)\s*($)?\b[^{]*\s*)\s*($)?{
```