# Using C++ strstr to find a c string and then count

Tags: c++

I'm using strstr in order to display the name of a class in c++. The problem with my code is is that it looks for this string :

```
"class "
```

throughout the input file. So the result looks like this:

```
The CLASS name is class locCounter 
The CLASS name is class ";
```

The second line should not be there, it's basically displaying line 7 from the code below, which it shouldn't.

```
int locCounter::classCounter()
{
    int count = 0;
    ifstream theOtherFile ("loc2.cpp");
    while (! theOtherFile.eof())
    {
        const char *one = "class ";
        getline(theOtherFile, otherFileData);
        const char *result = otherFileData.c_str();
        while ((result = strstr(result, one)) != NULL)
        {
            cout << "The CLASS name is " << result << endl;
            result++;
        }
    }
}
```

Other than that, I'm wondering how I can get the function to also start counting the number of lines from the time it find the word "class " until it hits the last curly bracket in the  class.

Thanks.

Comment: Use proper C++ parser, as your approach will not work, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318347/library-to-parse-c-c-source-code

Comment: Basically, you want a full C++ parser. There's much more to C++ than `class C {...};`. Besides string literals, there are things like `template <class T> void f();` or `class {int x;} v;`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - I know, but for now, I really just need it to find the class name and some of the function names.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while ((result = strstr(result, one)) != NULL)
```

to

```
if ((result = strstr(result, one)) != NULL)
```

The while loop looks for all the occurrences of `"class "` in your file, and the if statement looks for just the first occurrence.

Comment: Then you can break out of the loop once you encounter the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try a regular expression engine, such as [Boost Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)

Then you can use regexes like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597597/regular-expressions-to-find-class-declarations-in-c-code) to feed them to the engine.

Give it a try. It's really simple.